# Python interpreter exits when loading DLL

Tags: c++, python, ctypes

I want to test wrapping a dll with *ctypes*. I've written the following test code and compiled it using Code::Blocks and Cygwin to a dll.

```
#define DLL_EXPORT extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)

DLL_EXPORT int sum(int a, int b) {
    return a + b;
}
```

*Note: This is the whole code. Maybe there is something missing ?*

Now, I copy the `TestDll.dll` to my Desktop and start the Python interpreter. But when I want to load it, the interpreter just exits !

```
C:\Users\niklas\Desktop>python
Python 2.7.2 (default, Jun 12 2011, 15:08:59) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win 32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import ctypes
>>> dll = ctypes.WinDLL('TestDll')

C:\Users\niklas\Desktop>
```

However, loading any other library works, or giving an error if the library could not be found.
**Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong here ?**

Using Cygwin g++ 3.4.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check `objdump -p TestDll.dll | grep dll` to see if you've linked in "cygwin1.dll" and `nm TestDll.dll | grep Dll` to see if you have a `DllMain`. The following command should build the DLL correctly:

```
g++ testdll.c -mno-cygwin -shared -o TestDll.dll
```

Also, you need to use CDLL for the cdecl calling convention, not WinDLL:

```
>>> import ctypes
>>> dll = ctypes.CDLL('TestDll')
>>> dll.sum(4, 5)
9
```

Edit: I compiled with `i686-w64-mingw32-g++.exe` (4.5.3) from the Cygwin repository, but I used to use the default Cygwin gcc without a problem, given the -mno-cygwin option.

Comment: Yippie, using `ctypes.CDLL` fixes the problem encountered at the comment of Ignacios post. But using Cygwin still fails, even with theese commands. And no, the dll does not have a `dllmain`. Why does it have to ? It works without it using MinGw. :)

Answer (score 1):

As a complete guess, I'd say that the Cygwin-built DLL is incompatible with the MSVC-built interpreter, either because of a ABI issue or just because you can't use two different libcs. Build the DLL with MinGW instead.

Comment: Lol, now that's funny ^^. Works ! Well, generally. It doesn't exit anymore ! But `dll.sum` doesn't take 8 bytes as expected, it doesn't take any. I need to call it without any arguments and it returns `2620428`. Thanks !