# Load dll compiled by cygwin in python3

Tags: python, c, python-3.x, dll, ctypes

One of the function that my python application needs is heavy on math, so I decided that it can be written in C. This is simple function, but with lot of ifs and loops, so let's change it here to something shorter:

```
#define reduction 0.2
typedef long long int lint;

__declspec(dllexport) lint __cdecl min(lint x, lint y) { return (x<y?x:y); }

__declspec(dllexport) int __cdecl fight(lint a, lint b, lint c)
{
    float stack = 1;
    while (stack < a)
    {
        stack+= min(reduction*a*3, c+reduction);
    }
    return (int)stack;
}
```

The real function is more complex, but note that there is no includes or any other dependencies.

To compilt this to dll I'm using cygwin x64 (my python is also x64)

`gcc -c fight.c && gcc -o fight.dll -s -shared fight.o -Wl,--subsystem,windows`

MWE of python code that does not work is:

```
import os, pathlib
from ctypes import util, WinDLL

p = pathlib.Path(__file__).parent.absolute()
os.add_dll_directory(p)
c_lib = WinDLL(util.find_library("fight"))
```

I have already tried every combination of path (abs, rel) passed to WinDLL or CDLL or add_dll and error is the same:

```
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
FileNotFoundError: Could not find module 'fight.dll' (or one of its dependencies). Try using the full path with constructor syntax.
```

Comment: Your code compiles and runs with MSVC (`cl /LD fight.c`, /LD switch compiles and links a DLL in one step), loaded with `CDLL('./fight')` (no addlibrary/loadlibrary required and assuming it is in the local directory).  I don't have cygwin installed.  Note CDLL/WinDLL only matter on x86 so both work on x64.

Comment: Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8037306/python-interpreter-exits-when-loading-dll/8037620#8037620) Seem relevant.